# How do I move a maximized window from one monitor to another?

Tags: display, big-sur, multitasking, intel

I am new to macos and I am not able to move maximized windows from one monitor to another. Is it possible in mac?

I am using macOS Big Sur, Version 11.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to switch a full screen window from one monitor to another using [Rectangle App](https://rectangleapp.com/) in three steps:

1. Exit Full Screen mode using `Command+Control+F`
2. Move the window to any display using the shortcuts given by Rectangle App.
   `Ctrl+Option+Command+Left` to move it to the previous display and `Ctrl+Option+Command+Right` to move it to the next display.
3. Enter full screen mode back using `Command+Control+F`

Answer (score 4):

Are both displays the same resolution? [Not the same physical size, that's not important.]
Are you confusing 'maximised' with 'fullscreen'?

You can move any window, maximised or not, by dragging the title bar. You cannot move fullscreen apps this way. You need to invoke Mission Control & drag the mini icon in the large top bar that appears. This only works if you have 'Displays have separate Spaces' *checked*, otherwise any fullscreen app will just blank out the second display.

For fullscreen…

[image]

Mockup of fullscreen app without Separate Spaces…

[image]

If your displays are disparate resolutions & not Separate Spaces, then if you line them up like this, with the tops aligned, in System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement

[image]

then you will find it easier to drag between them, along the top of either display. You may need to just bump round the menu bar in this instance, going from right to left.
…or maybe offset them by the depth of the menu bar, like so…

[image]

Comment: Thankyou @Tetsujin for the answer. But I want to move the window to the same desktop. I found a way to do it. Will be adding an answer

Comment: "move the window to the same desktop" - I don't understand what you mean. You mean the same physical display but another Space? That wasn't at all clear from your question. You don't need an app to do that, just hold the title bar & use whatever key commands you already have set up to select that Space. Default is Ctrl/[number] or Ctrl/left or right arrow. [You still can't do that for fullscreen, as fullscreen windows don't have 'real Spaces'. Your answer below doesn't answer the question you asked.